# plt.plot after a keyboard input

Tags: python, input, plot, keypress

I'd like to update a plot with different colors with different keypress. But using the following code, the figure only shows in the very end, after pressing 'q'.

Can anyone please give some suggestions? Thanks!

Example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

b=1

while b:
  a=input('Enter a key: ...')

  if a=='b': #plot with blue color if press 'b'
     plt.plot(np.arange(10),color='b')
     plt.draw()

  elif a=='r': #plot with red color if press 'r'
     plt.plot(np.arange(10),color='r')
     plt.draw()

  elif a=='q':
     b=0
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried your code without success. For me, no plot showed up even after pressing q. I don't know enough to say if this has to do with the version of matplotlib, your operating system backend, or Python version.

I've changed it to the following... It seems to work, albeit with the ugly addition of some "first time" code with the key change to `plt.show(block=False)`. The `block=False` lets the script continue while plt is being displayed.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

b=1

# First time
a=raw_input('Enter a key: ...')
if a=='b': #plot with blue color if press 'b'
    plt.plot(np.arange(10),color='b')
    plt.show(block=False)

elif a=='r': #plot with red color if press 'r'
    plt.plot(np.arange(10),color='r')
    plt.show(block=False)


# update
while b:
    a=raw_input('Enter a key: ...')

    if a=='b': #plot with blue color if press 'b'
        plt.plot(np.arange(10),color='b')
        plt.draw()

    elif a=='r': #plot with red color if press 'r'
        plt.plot(np.arange(10),color='r')
        plt.draw()

    elif a=='q':
        b=0
```

I hope there's some nicer way to do this.